# Changing css for specific user depends of php variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress theme which make and post new div with unique id for episode `<div class = "post-2122 episode type-episode status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">` and how can i change border in css only for specific user and dependable on php variable? post-xxxx is uniquefor every episode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could also add the user ID in body_class()

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_class_names' );
function my_class_names( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    global $current_user;
    $user_ID = $current_user->ID;
    $classes[] = 'user-id-' . $user_ID;
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a special border on specific user when is logged, you can try :

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<div class="is-logged">';
} else {
    echo '<div>';
}
?>
```

And then apply a CSS to .is-logged

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since `is_user_logged_in()` only checks if a user is logged in, not a specific user. Also, your answer should apply to the OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<div class="post-<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?> episode type-episode status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
```

here is the reference [how to get post id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

hope your problem will be solve.!

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is asking to get the user information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_current_user_id()` to get the logged in ID of the user.

```
   <?php $user = 'user_' . get_current_user_id(); ?>
   
   <div class="<?php echo $user; ?> post-2122 episode type-episode status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
```

If the user is not logged in, `$user` will echo `user_0`, if they are logged in, `$user` will echo `user_xx` with their ID in place of `xx`.

Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/